# Processmaker 4.8.3 is stuck in login page and won't going further

Tags: php, laravel, workflow, bitnami, processmaker

I have installed processmaker 4.8.3 using the instruction given in ([https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker#:~:text=Before%20installing%2C%20Nginx,and%20restart%20horizon](https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker#:%7E:text=Before%20installing%2C%20Nginx,and%20restart%20horizon)) on my machine running on ubuntu 22.04. It installed properly but stucked on login page.

After running the following command

```
npx laravel-echo-server start
php artisan horizon
```

I am getting OK on http://127.0.0.1:6001 and after running the folloing command

```
php artisan serve
```

It takes me to login screen on http://127.0.0.1:8000 . After that it does nothing if I give correct or wrong credentials. If i turn on debug mode it shows

> Class "Laravel\Telescope\IncomingEntry" not found

What should I do next?

Comment: you need to install composer dependencies, `composer install` and then after you setup your .env file, generate the key `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: I have done this. but still not working.

Comment: Try `php artisan telescope:install`

Comment: There was some version dependency. I have fixed it. and it is working now. Thanks for your help. :D